# How to run External .exe File through Windows Server

Tags: c#

how can I run External  .exe  File through Windows Server ?

thank's

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, but this likely belongs on www.serverfault.com anyway.

Comment: @adam: which is not up yet. so what.

Comment: @divo: so what means it likely isn't programming-related. I thought it might be nicer to say something helpful rather than something glib. I see our philosophies differ on that point.

Comment: @Adam. How's someone supposed to know about server fault? It's not up, and not announced apart from the SO blog. Not everyone here reads the SO blog.

Comment: @tony: that's why I mentioned it. If he has questions like this in the future, he can check there (assuming it's up by then)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more info to help you out better. You are asking us how to start an application and you have tagged it as c# so I assume you are asking how you can start an application/process using c#. If so the check the following link

[Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) using which you can run a local or remote process.